# Dynamically Change select option when checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Changing the select options on clicking check boxes, i have list of 8 check boxes dynamically it counts checked check boxes for example if i click on 1 check box it will show Number Of Credits Selected : 1 , and if i click on 2 check boxes it will show Number Of Credits Selected : 2 and soon,

below the check boxes i have select options i want dynamically change of select option when check boxes are checked 
example : if i click on two check boxes my select option should change to 2 selected and so on.

can somebody help me out in achieving it!

thanks!

Here is an demo example http://jsfiddle.net/Qac6J/552/

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container" >
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="no_of_credits">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1  class="print_no_of_credits">Number Of Credits Selected : 0</h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <form class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="1 selected">1 selected</option>
                    <option value="2 selected">2 selected</option>
                    <option value="3 selected">3 selected</option>
                    <option value="4 selected">4 selected</option>
                    <option value="5 selected">5 selected</option>
                    <option value="6 selected">6 selected</option>
                    <option value="7 selected">7 selected</option>
                    <option value="8 selected">8 selected</option>
                    <option value="9 selected">9 selected</option>
                    <option value="10 selected">10 selected</option>
                    <option value="11 selected">11 selected</option>
                    <option value="12 selected">12 selected</option>
                </select> 
        </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function()
            {
                var total = ($('.no_of_credits:checked').length)+0;
                $(".print_no_of_credits").html( "<h1>Number Of Credits Selected : "+total+"</h1>" ).length;
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the below line to your `click event`

```
$('.form-control').val(total + " selected");
```

So your updated code would be:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var total = ($('.no_of_credits:checked').length) + 0;
    $(".print_no_of_credits").html("<h1>Number Of Credits Selected : " + total + "</h1>").length;
    $('.form-control').val(total + " selected");
});
```

## [`UPDATED FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Qac6J/553/)

**Update**

---

You can modify your `var total` calculation as

```
var total=$('.no_of_credits:checked').length
```

Comment: Thanks @Guruprasad.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)